# Why are margins in CSS inconsistent and behaving strange?

Tags: html, css

I was playing with a slideshow in jQuery today. I managed to create it when I noticed strange thing. The div `#feature` in which the slideshow is placed seems to be somehow glued to its parent element `#content`. When I add `margin: 10px auto` to the `#feature` div, the `#content` div is also lowered down by 10px relative to its parent element.

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong here?

Providing you with the whole code would create a mess, but here's a link:

CSS for `#feature`:

```
#feature {
    width:940px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    height:500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
}
```

and CSS for `#content`:

```
#content{
    min-height:800px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

My friend noticed an interesting thing. If you add `margin-bottom: 30px` to `#menu` the empty 10px space in content is filled correctly although the margin problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to `#content`. It may help.

Adding overflow prevents margins from collapsing

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin.

from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: Your answer seems to do the trick :) Thank you. Could you explain me though how does it work, why `overflow: auto` fixes it?

Comment: As I can understand overflow:auto tells #content to count all margins of inner divs as space inside # content div.

Answer (score 3):

`position: relative` does just that... makes any element that this applies to have its position become "relative" to its parent container.

`#feature` is a child of `#content`, so `#feature`'s position becomes relative to the position of `#content`. When you add that 10px margin to #feature, it moves down 10px from `#content`.

Comment: That's the problem it doesn't. It moves content 10px down relative to the #body